# Argument of type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSON[]'

Tags: json, typescript

I have a file (.json) with the content:

```
[
    {
        "key": "string1"
    },
    {
        "key": "string2"
    }
]
```

As far as I understand this file represents JSON[] type.

Then in my typescript class, I import it by the statement:

```
import file from "../path/file.json";
```

and then I want to pass it as an argument to a function which expects an argument of `JSON[]` type.

I defined a type of the method in `index.d.ts` like this:

```
takeJsonFile(file: JSON[]): any
```

But when I pass the `file` to a method:

```
takeJsonfile(file);
```

I get the error message:

```
Argument of type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSON[]'.
  Type '{ key: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'JSON': parse, stringify, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2345)
```

my `tsconfig.json` includes:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],...
```

What am I missing here? Is the file I am trying to pass not of `JSON[]` type? Why? I thought that

```
{
   "key": "value"
}
```

represents a `JSON` type of object and more of it in an array represents `JSON[]` type of object.

Comment: `JSON` type represents the native [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) JavaScript global object so this is not the type you want

Comment: You have to post the code that throws the exception

Comment: Your file is currently in string format.
You need to parse it to JSON.
JSON.parse(file)

Comment: @toptecshare I get "Argument of type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)" then.

Comment: @Guerric P - so which type I should use then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create a custom type

```
type KeyValue = {
  key: string;
};
```

or class (I don't know your version)

```
class KeyValue {
  key: string;

  constructor(key: string) {
    this.key = key;
  }
}
```

and use

```
function GetKeyValue(items:KeyValue[]){
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the first line and it is working well.
Here is the code.

src/index.ts

```
const file = require("../file.json");
export function takeJsonFile(file: JSON[]): any {
  console.log(file[0]);
}
takeJsonFile(file);
```

file.json

```
[
  {
    "key": "string1"
  },
  {
    "key": "string2"
  }
]
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```